# Inject components attached to child GameObjects of prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine, zenject

I use Factories to create GameObjects from prefabs.

```
MenuScreen (prefab root game object)
  * MenuScreenComponent <- inject ScreensNavigator
  - Button (game object)
    * ButtonSoundBehaviour <- inject AssetsProvider
```

In the installer:

```
Container.BindFactory<MenuScreen, MenuScreen.Factory>().FromComponentInNewPrefab(MenuFragmentPrefab);
```

`ScreensNavigator` injected into `MenuScreenComponent` without any problems.

How to make `ButtonSoundBehaviour` to be injected with `AssetsProvider`?
I tried to add `Zenject Binding` to Button GameObject but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell zenject where to find AssetsProvider by adding a binding for it on the container.

For example, if you add `Container.Bind<AssetsProvider>().AsSingle()` to an installer, then ButtonSoundBehaviour will have AssetsProvider injected into it.